# ¿Cómo hacer que la gráfica lineal quede dentro de la altura de la gráfica de barras a que pertenece en chartjs?

Tags: chart.js

Quiero que el % Selectivo se muestre dentro de la gráfica de barras de Total Selectivo, y el % Resto dentro de Total Resto. Es decir que
cojan el 100% de cada gráfica de barras y en función de su % se muevan en el rango de esa barra.
Gráfica de barras en stack (3 barras), con 2 lineales que me da este problema.

```
<script>
var data = {
    labels: ['2012', '2014', '2015', '2016', '2017', '2018', '2019', '2020'],
    datasets: [
        {
            label: 'Total Selectivo',
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
            borderColor: 'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
            borderWidth: 1,
            type: 'bar',
            data: [6522002, 6419769, 6343909, 7294915, 7950973, 7797424, 8451121, 8919822],
            yAxisID: 'bar-y-axis',
            stack: 'Stack 2',
            hoverBackgroundColor: 'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.4)',
            hoverBorderColor: 'rgba(75, 192, 192, 2)',
            datalabels: {
                align: 'center',
                anchor: 'center',
                formatter: function (value, context) {
                    return (value / 1000000).toFixed(2) + 't';
                },
            },
        },
        {
            label: '% Selectivo',
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
            borderColor: 'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
            data: [29.79, 30.81, 29.98, 33.86, 36.11, 35.02, 37.96, 40.56],
            yAxisID: 'line-y-axis',
            type: 'line',
            hoverBorderColor: 'rgba(75, 192, 192, 2)',
            hoverBackgroundColor: 'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.4)',
            datalabels: {
                align: 'end',
                anchor: 'end',
                formatter: function (value, context) {
                    return value.toFixed(2) + '%';
                },
            },
        },
        {
            label: 'Total Resto',
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)',
            borderColor: 'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)',
            borderWidth: 1,
            type: 'bar',
            data: [15374333, 14416639, 14813919, 14246925, 14066891, 14467399, 13810568, 13069494],
            yAxisID: 'bar-y-axis',
            stack: 'Stack 2',
            hoverBackgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.4)',
            hoverBorderColor: 'rgba(255, 159, 64, 2)',
            datalabels: {
                align: 'center',
                anchor: 'center',
                formatter: function (value, context) {
                    return (value / 1000000).toFixed(2) + 't';
                },
            },
        },
        {
            label: '% Resto',
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)',
            borderColor: 'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)',
            data: [70.21, 69.19, 70.02, 66.14, 63.89, 64.98, 62.04, 59.44],
            yAxisID: 'line-y-axis',
            type: 'line',
            hoverBorderColor: 'rgba(255, 159, 64, 2)',
            hoverBackgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.4)',
            datalabels: {
                align: 'end',
                anchor: 'end',
                formatter: function (value, context) {
                    return value.toFixed(2) + '%';
                },
            },
        },
        {
            label: 'Suma Total ',
            type: 'bar',
            data: [20.20, 20.84, 21.16, 21.54, 22.02, 22.26, 22.26, 21.99],
            yAxisID: 'bar-y-axis',
            stack: 'Stack 2',
            datalabels: {
                align: 'top',
                anchor: 'center',
                formatter: function (value, context) {
                    return 'Total ' + value + 't';
                },
            },
        },
    ],
};

config = {
    type: 'bar',
    data,
    options: {
        interaction: {
            intersect: false,
            mode: 'index',
        },
        plugins: {
            tooltip: {
                mode: 'index',
                intersect: false,
            },
            legend: {
                position: 'bottom',
                align: 'center',
            },
            datalabels: {
                display: function (context) {
                    return context.dataset.type === 'line' || context.dataset.type === 'bar';
                },
            },
        },
        scales: {
            'bar-y-axis': {
                type: 'linear',
                display: true,
                position: 'left',
                grid: {
                    drawOnChartArea: false,
                },
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero: true,
                    precision: 0,
                    callback: function (value) {
                        return (value / 1000000) + 't';
                    },
                },
            },
            'line-y-axis': {
                type: 'linear',
                display: true,
                position: 'right', // Cambia la posición a 'right' para mostrar el eje Y a la derecha
                grid: {
                    drawOnChartArea: false,
                },
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero: true,
                    max: 100,
                    callback: function (value) {
                        return value + '%';
                    },
                },
            },
        },
        hover: {
            mode: 'index',
            intersect: true,
        },
    },
    plugins: [ChartDataLabels],
};

const myChart = new Chart(document.getElementById('bar_Chart'), config);
</script>
```

---

Hay dos graficas de barras en modo stack (una encima de la otra) y luego añado 2 graficas lineales cada cual representa el % del valor del histograma del total.

Total Resto --> % Resto
Total Selectivo --> % Selectivo
Si sumas ambos TR y TS sale el Total generado que es el 100%.

Quiero que cada grafica lineal %Resto y %Selectivo, la linia solo se mueva dentro de la altura de cada respectivo histograma. Es decir, en mi caso añado otro eje Y a la derecha con el %, pero esto hace que las lineas no tengan una correlación con la proporcionalidad de los histogramas. Quiero que de manera ficiticia el % de cada uno con sus respectivos histogramas, sea su 100%.

Me lo invento en Total selectivo hay 4t y eso de manera ficiticia haremos que sea el 100% cogiendo solo el %Selectivo para que aparezca dentro de esa unica barra en stack y lo mismo con la otra. Así los textos de histograma y lineal no se superponen ya que mantienen la correlación dentro.
Igualito a la imagen pero con otra grafica bar en modo stack, junto su propia lineal dentro del bar. Espero que no te haya liado más, disculpa mi manera de expresar.

Y gracias por ofrecerte a proporcionar una solución a algo que no consigo que me salga!!
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No entiendo el problema, puedes volver a explicarlo?? preferentemente usando imágenes